# Is there a way to report/remove frivolous tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are quite a few tags that are completely unneeded such as [2012](/questions/tagged/2012) and [vs](/questions/tagged/vs).

Is there a way to report these tags?

Comment: There was only one question with those. I retagged it `visual-studio-2012`. The tags should be gone soon due to automatic cleanup.

Comment: Wait, since when did we allow pure-numeric tags again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have enough reputation and there aren't too many questions with the tags, you can untag them. Tags which do not have any questions are removed from the system after a period of inactivity.

If there are a large number of tagged questions, it is not uncommon for people to post the tags here for help in untagging; in cases which would require more, e.g. tags which keep coming back or a needed synonym, this is also the place to ask for help for either burnination or synonyms from the mods and dev team.

It looks like the tags you mentioned do not have any questions, so they should automatically be removed by the system eventually.

Answer (score 6):

You have enough rep to [retag questions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions). Remove the tags yourself, and they will disappear after 24 hours if nobody uses them.