# Flagging tags for deletion

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I accidentally created a tag. How do I delete it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it)
>   [Is there a way to report/remove frivolous tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157941/is-there-a-way-to-report-remove-frivolous-tags)

I just found the tag [xlw](/questions/tagged/xlw) which is a typo of [xls](/questions/tagged/xls) but I don't find a way to flag this tag for deletion.

I searched also for a dublicate of this question but I found nothing.

Comment: I asked pretty much the same thing 12 hours ago :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157941/200868

Comment: Welcome to the New Tag Deletionist Cabal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term is *burnination*:

> burnination [ˈbərn:əˈneɪʃən] (noun)
>   The process of incinerating an object
>   through the use of a dragon

Put in a request here on meta when you see tags that need merging/burnination, and the mods will do it for you.

If you see tags that are only on a few questions, untag them; the system will automatically delete tags after a period of inactivity. You can, once again, ask for help here on meta with untagging.

Comment: I removed the tag so it will be deleted automatically thank you.