# Why doesn't accepting an answer count as an upvote?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, up-votes

When you accept an answer, it seems you should also (by etiquette?) upvote the answer. Why doesn't the checkmark count as an automatic upvote?

Comment: How would anyone get Unsung Hero?

Comment: @Rapptz Assuming the automatic upvoted only applies to users with >= 15 rep, then it's possible. Or if the OP for some reason undoes the automatic upvote.

Comment: Did you ever feel that the answer was correct but did not deserve an upvote?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157940/isnt-it-redundant-to-vote-up-the-answer-you-have-chosen-to-your-own-question/157947#157947

Comment: Checkmark == correct; Up Vote == helpful; correct !=(always) helpful;

Comment: There are plenty of times when the correct answer is written in a way that you would also downvote it

Comment: @SteveKonves No, acceptance is not equivalent to correctness. It *only* means that the OP chose it. All too often the OP is not very well qualified to judge answers and selects one that either doesn't do what they asked or does it so poorly, inefficiently or inelegantly that it can't be called "correct" for all that it's get their eventually.

Comment: @dmckee yes, this is true. ... `checkmark == OP.IsCorrect(); upvote == Community.IsHelpful();`

Comment: @SteveKonves Brilliant.

Comment: I'm talking about OP.IsHelpful() not Community.IsHelpful()

Comment: juergend: no. You very quickly get into weird, pointless, meta questions like "how much effort did they put into that answer?" and "is that always true?"

Comment: @SteveBennett - Use `@username` to [reply anyone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Otherwise they won't get notification. :)

Comment: @juergend hey, you!

Comment: You haven't truly experienced Stack Overflow until an OP accepts your heavily down voted answer.  You can't always get what you want.  But if you try sometimes you just might find you get what you need.

Answer (score 13):

They're not as redundant as it would be confusing to have it automatically apply.  It's UI complexity with no benefit.  If you upvote then accept a day later it'll be little confusing to see the inconsistency in adding a +1 vote on accept.  And the logic shouldn't apply to self-accepts.

Furthermore I would rather new users understand these as two distinct features.  "Does an accept count as an upvote?" shouldn't ever need to be asked.

Simpler business rules = better.

Comment: Reading the other comments, people are describing situations where it's valuable to distinguish between "correct" and "helpful". But people seem to have different ideas of what it means to accept an answer but not upvote it. Leading me to think that this feature is actually not helpful at all, and just confusing.

Comment: @SteveBennett it's not a feature.  It's just default behavior that follows from having an "accept" feature and an "upvote" feature.  The decoupled-ness of these features isn't confusing.  Why users accept but don't upvote is confusing.  But it's not more confusing than any other capricious nonsensical reasons users choose to upvote or not upvote something, it just stands out more since there's a check mark next to it.

Answer (score 3):

If I asked a question and was presented with a functioning code dump but no explanation as to how it functioned I would likely accept the answer, as it would technically be correct.
However I would not upvote it as nothing had been put forth to explain and assist in educating anyone reading the answer.

I often see this sort of response to LINQ questions where a couple of comments next to lines could go a long way, rather than just handing out the functioning code.

I would basically use it to differentiate between a technically correct answer and a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, other than suggesting etiquette you've failed to provide a reason why a marked answer should be up voted.

An up vote is an indication that you think the answer has merit or was helpful. Marking it as the answer simply means that the answer helped you the most for your particular question. An answer can be correct and marked as the answer, but still be a terrible answer. There are also times where an OP will select their own answer - of course this cannot be up voted automatically.

Marking an answer and up voting an answer are two different things - don't try to morph them together.

*Also remember that the policy on the site is that voting (up or down) is not forced or mandatory, and doesn't have to be justified. Automatic up votes would be at odds with that policy.*

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if my comment on the question is diametrically apposed to your answer ...

Comment: Do you ever accept an answer that doesn't have merit?

Comment: You can upvote multiple answers, but you can only accept one. When you accept an answer but upvote another, do you not also upvote the accepted answer? If not, why not? (If it doesn't have merit, why accept it?)

Comment: @SteveKonves I think we are saying the same thing - your comment wasn't there when I wrote the answer.

Comment: @djechlin You've missed the point - just because you've accepted it doesn't mean it automatically deserves an up vote. Merit is one reason - you might also wish to promote other answers above it even though they aren't checked. There can be a bunch of reasons why you want or don't want to up vote something.

Comment: Firstly, you make the claim, "Just because you mark it as correct doesn't mean it is an answer with merit."  Can you substantiate this?  It sounds false. Secondly, you state, "An up vote is an indication that you think the answer has merit."  Now you're saying that merit is only one reason; if that's what you are claiming your answer should reflect this.  But I think this is an uphill argument to make, even the mouseover above the upvote says "This answer is useful."  Then again I don't always upvote useful answers - but I never don't upvote useful answers that I also accept.

Comment: @djechlin I don't have to substantiate anything just because it *"sounds false"* to you. Please refer back to what I (and others in comments) said - correct and helpful are two separate things and should be treated as such. *Merit* and *helpful* are synonymous as far as I'm concerned. I'm not sure how much clearer I could be? As an example, I'm sure you must have seen answers that were correct but were still terrible (I have) - do they deserve an up vote simply because they were marked as correct?

Comment: @djechlin I've rephrased my answer somewhat - maybe it will make my meaning clearer. I've just read your answer and it's funny how we are both arguing for the same thing, just citing different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of this stems from "low rep" users not understanding the system (granted people who know what they're doing also accept without an upvote, but it is less frequent). I would propose that:

Just like everytime a "low rep" user [**downvotes** they are met with an alertbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes/2373#2373):

> Please consider adding a comment
>   if you think this post can be improved.

Why not say a similar alert everytime a ("low", but [at least 15](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up), rep) user **accepts** an answer:

> Please consider upvoting
>   if this answer is helpful to you.

*I claim that many new users don't realise when they have gone over 15 rep and can upvote*, and I think if prompted would (in my experience are often eager to) upvote, as discussed in [Is it bad form to prompt new questioners to formally accept your answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12543/is-it-bad-form-to-prompt-new-questioners-to-formally-accept-your-answer).*

*I realise they currently receive a notification of their new privilege.

Comment: dang, this has totally already been thought of 2 years ago (but not implemented?) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79347/reminding-new-users-of-accept-upvote-duty